# Weird "name does not exist in current context" bug

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I'm debugging the following code snippet in Visual Studio 2015:

```
Stream xmlFileStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceFilePath);
if (xmlFileStream != null)
{
    var reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFileStream);
    XDocument schemaDefinition = XDocument.Load(reader); // NullReference
    ...
```

The last line throws a `NullReferenceException`, so I started debugging and I have the weirdest situation:

[image: Debugging screenshot]

So, the line where the NullReferenceException is thrown, the line below the declaration/initialization of `reader`, I'm getting that `reader` does not exist.

How is this possible? I've even restarted my computer and I've cleaned+rebuilt the project a dozen times.

More info:

- The code is run from a unit test (NUnit) using Resharper's unit test runners.
- Target framework is .NET 4 (both the test and the code assembly)
- `xmlFileStream` looks fine at that point

Further up the call stack there seems to be something related to threading (I'm not familiar enough with the project yet to determine why it's used):

```
lock (Threadlock)
{
    if (!SchemaConfigurations.Keys.Contains(dialect))
    {
        SchemaConfigurations.Add(dialect, new SchemaConfiguration
        {
            /*DOING THIS*/ MessageStructureConfigurations = ReadMessageStructureConfiguration(dialect),
            SegmentConfigurations = ReadSegmentConfiguration(dialect),
            DataTypeConfigurations = ReadDataTypeConfiguration(dialect),
            MessageTypeLocation = _messageTypeLocation,
            TriggerEventLocation = _triggerEventLocation
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the IL (using ILSpy):

```
IL_0000: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class Ihc.Integration.ParserBuilder.Hl7.Core.SchemaConfigurations.Domain.SegmentConfiguration>::.ctor()
IL_0005: stloc.0
IL_0006: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class Ihc.Integration.ParserBuilder.Hl7.Core.SchemaConfigurations.Domain.SegmentConfiguration>::.ctor()
IL_000b: stloc.1
IL_000c: ldstr "{0}.Hl7.Core.SchemaConfigurations.Schemas.{1}_Segments.xml"
IL_0011: call class [mscorlib]System.Reflection.Assembly [mscorlib]System.Reflection.Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()
IL_0016: callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Reflection.AssemblyName [mscorlib]System.Reflection.Assembly::GetName()
IL_001b: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.Reflection.AssemblyName::get_Name()
IL_0020: ldarg.0
IL_0021: box Ihc.Integration.ParserBuilder.Hl7.Interfaces.SupplierType
IL_0026: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string, object, object)
IL_002b: stloc.2
IL_002c: call class [mscorlib]System.Reflection.Assembly [mscorlib]System.Reflection.Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()
IL_0031: ldloc.2
IL_0032: callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.IO.Stream [mscorlib]System.Reflection.Assembly::GetManifestResourceStream(string)
IL_0037: stloc.3
IL_0038: ldloc.3
IL_0039: brfalse IL_0339

IL_003e: ldloc.3
IL_003f: call class [System.Xml]System.Xml.XmlReader [System.Xml]System.Xml.XmlReader::Create(class [mscorlib]System.IO.Stream)
IL_0044: call class [System.Xml.Linq]System.Xml.Linq.XDocument [System.Xml.Linq]System.Xml.Linq.XDocument::Load(class [System.Xml]System.Xml.XmlReader)
IL_0049: stloc.s 4
IL_004b: ldloc.s 4
```

Comment: Are you debugging a release build by any chance?

Comment: There's been some weird JIT bugs floating around lately. Can you post the IL and the ngened disassembly?

Comment: @Asad Those would not apply to .NET 4.0, would they?

Comment: @Asad tbh I've never done that before, looking into that now

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester There is no way this is a race condition?

Comment: @Petrichor I'm not sure. .NET 4.6 is an in place upgrade, so I'm not sure if targeting .NET 4 actually uses an older JIT or if the new JIT is still used. From tests earlier, targeting .NET 4.5 didn't fix issues that were introduced with .NET 4.6 and RyuJIT.

Comment: @Petrichor Still, investigating obvious problems like race conditions first is the correct approach here. I'm still a bit rattled by the bugs I saw and leapt to conclusions :). OP, is this code multithreaded?

Comment: @Petrichor (and Asad) I posted the calling code, there is a lock there but I cannot say why yet (I'm new to this project). Can't see why the code that goes wrong would be multithreaded though.

Comment: Multithreading is used in another unit test unrelated to this one, so it can't be a race condition.

Comment: @JonSkeet Everything is built from visual studio, using debug config.

Comment: @JonSkeet Turns out you had the solution. See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Someone had messed up the configuration in the `.sln` file. All projects were set to be built in `release` config even if the "active" config was `debug`.

We generate `.pdb` files in release mode so that's why debugging still worked fine... until that one variable mysteriously disappeared.